# Doubt on the comparison test: can I still evaluate $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$ if $b_{n}$ might be $0$ for some $n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(b_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence which is not identically equal to $0$ (but which may have elements equal to $0$). Suppose also that I know that $\sum b_{n}$ converges absolutely.
If I want to verify if another series $\sum |a_{n}|$ converges, can I use the comparison test, that is:$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n}|}{|b_{n}|} = c \neq 0 \implies \sum |a_{n}|$$ converges? The problem here is that I might have $0$ in the denominator...

Comment: Well if you know all the terms after some point are non-zero, then yes. Also If you know that all the $a_n$ are non-zero at some point you could switch numerator and denominator.

Comment: If there are infinitely many $n$ such that $b_n=0$, you can't use Comparison because the limit does not exist. If $a_n=0$ when $b_n=0$, or more generally if the sum of the $|a_n|$ when $b_n=0$ converges, then you can use Comparison on the rest of the $n$.

Comment: If i happens that $b_n = 0 $ implies $a_n = 0$, you can.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot apply the limit comparison test if $b_n = 0$ for very many $n$. There are a few conditions when you can, however.

1. If $b_n$ is eventually nonzero (i.e. if there is some $N > 0$ so that $b_n \neq 0$ for all $n > N$), then you can apply limit comparison. This is because the first finitely many terms don't contribute to the eventual convergence or divergence of the sums.
2. If $a_n = 0$ whenever $b_n = 0$, then you can apply limit comparison. Morally, you can think of these terms of just never having been there at all. I have a hard time imagining non-contrived examples of this behaviour.
3. As André Nicolas mentioned in a comment: split $\mathbb{N}$ into $\{ m : b_m = 0\}$ and $\{ n : b_n \neq 0 \}$. Then if the limit
   $$ \lim \frac{\lvert a_n \rvert}{\lvert b_n \rvert} = c \neq 0$$
   converges and the sum
   $$ \sum_{m: b_m = 0} \lvert a_m \rvert < \infty,$$
   converges then the series associated to $a_i$ converges if and only if the series associated to $b_i$ converges.

It might also be worth noting that one can also say things when the limit is $0$, as this indicates that the series associated to $|a_i|$ is smaller in magnitude then the series associated to $|b_i|$.